# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar un logo desde la bd Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Tengo este código gracias a @nachospiu

```
SELECT TeamName, tag, Player01, Player02, Player03, Player04 
FROM (
  SELECT 
     user_id,
     MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'TeamName' THEN meta_value END) AS TeamName,
     MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'tag' THEN meta_value END) AS tag,
     MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'Player01' THEN meta_value END) AS Player01,
     MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'Player02' THEN meta_value END) AS Player02,
     MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'Player03' THEN meta_value END) AS Player03,
     MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'Player04' THEN meta_value END) AS Player04,
     MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'status' THEN meta_value END) AS status
  FROM wpuk_usermeta
  GROUP BY user_id) AS sq
WHERE status = 'aprobado';
```

Ahora lo que deseo es mostrar el logo de cada "TeamName"

Mi Tabla es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo este resultado incorporado el logo al final ....
Sobre el tamaño del logo cómo puedo hacer en miniatura? acorde al espacio que me genera los resultados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me pueden ayudar con esto?

Saludos.

Comment: No. No se que ide estas usando, pero las ide de bases de datos no hacen eso. Eso lo tenes que hacer cuando desarrolles un front y en el mismo vas a poder hacer todas esas cosas. Las ide de base de datos, solo sirven para manejar las bases y ver los datos...

Comment: Vi este tutorial... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vj9Sk6GcC2U&t=433s

No sé si me explico en ello, pero deseo algo similar.

Comment: Y el codigo en php que intentaste? porque aca solo mostras un sql...